# Prepending all instances of a string with a char

Tags: c#, regex, string, .net-2.0

I am using C#. NET 2.0 and WinForms.

I have a piece of code which is formatted in Assembly like this:

```
VARIABLE = 40
ADDRESS = $60

LDA VARIABLE;
STA ADDRESS;
```

Output should be:

```
!VARIABLE = 40
!ADDRESS = $60

LDA !VARIABLE;
STA !ADDRESS;
```

Of course, there is much more than that. Like 2000 lines, but the point is there are declarations at the top of the file and I can load/save or do whatever with them. But my problem is, I have to "prepend" ALL of these declarations (even in raw code) with a !.

My current method is this:

```
        var defs = tab.tb.GetRanges(@"^\s*([A-Za-z0-9_]+){4,255}\s*=", RegexOptions.Multiline); // all declarations are formatted like this, so use regex to get all of them
        foreach (var def in defs)
        {
            string actual = def.Text.Substring(0, def.Text.IndexOf(' ')); // remove the = sign since its not used in actual code
                txt = txt.Replace(actual, "!" + actual);
        }
```

However, this method is very slow. It takes approximately 3 seconds to "fix up" all of the declarations in my file. Is there any better way? And for the record, the syntax is slightly different from a normal text box because I am using http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/FastColoredTextBox_.aspx as my text control.

Comment: So in this example, you would want a `!` in front of `VARIABLE` and `ADDRESS` (lines 1 and 2) but not the rest? or you would have four `!` one in front of each line? Sample output would help me understand a bit

Comment: Off the top of my head, using a Regex Replace() rather than substrings + reallocating a new string over and over may be faster: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx

Comment: @TimMedora But how would you get the substring of the regex match then? My regex will return "VARIABLE =" and I need to replace all instances of "VARIABLE" only.

Comment: You could save the substring call if you make the `\s*=` a lookahead prior to the loop. But that won't accomplish much, I guess, as the strings in question are very short.

Comment: @david - you could use multiple capturing groups to capture the "variable" string in one group and ignore the group containing the "=". That could eliminate the substring. I would need to see the rest of the code to comment further (for instance, is "txt" the entire file?)

Comment: txt is a string contain all of the code in a file.

Comment: @TimMedora I just tried grouping the actual variable, but it doesn't make a difference in terms of performance.

Comment: @david - I'm building out a sample, I will post code if I can improve performance.

Comment: You could go line by line, grab all declarations in a list, then go over the code again and replace `(?=\<thewordhere\>)` with `!`

Comment: @fge: Could you elaborate, mainly on the replace part?

Comment: @david look at my answer -- your regex definitely has a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nest quantifiers in your regex!

```
([A-Za-z0-9_]+){4,255}
```

Take a simple string as 'aaaaaaaa': what is the regex engine supposed to capture? 'a' 8 times, 'aa' 4 times, 'aa', then 'a', then 'a', then... ?

This is very probably the cause of your performance problems. Just don't do that! All the more that you try to match in the *whole* file. Even though the regex engine will eventually choose the leftmost, longest match, it tries *all* possibilities, always.

Remove the `+`!

Comment: About the {4,255}, it should actually be {4,}, but that won't increase performance. And unless your method is different, this is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: See commit edit. In fact, just removing the `+` from your inital regex will very probably speed things  up.

Comment: You're right! When I removed the +, things seemed to be WAY faster. Come to think of it, I'm not sure why I even added it in the first place.

Comment: It tells you one thing at least: the .NET engine is NFA ;)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your performance problem lies in doing the replace on `str`.  Strings in .NET are immutable, so when you do any operation that changes the string (append, replace, etc.), .NET has to create a new string and copy the old one into it (all 2000 lines of it), plus the changes.  Try loading your string into a `StringBuilder` (which is mutable) instead and using it's native .Replace() method.

Comment: That seems to increase the speed by 0.1s, which is pretty good I guess. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick attempt. On my machine, this processes a 25000+ line file in < 100ms.

However, I only have the two sample values to base this off of; performance will degrade with more replace operations.

Update: I tried another sample, this time with 25000 lines and 8 unique values to modify. Performance only degraded by a few milliseconds.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
string text = File.ReadAllText( @"C:\\temp\so.txt" );

sw.Start();

// find the tokens we will be replacing
Regex tokenFinder = new Regex( @"^(([A-Za-z0-9_]+){4,255})\s*(=)", RegexOptions.Multiline );

// ensure uniqueness, and remove "=" by looking at the second match group
var tokens = ( from Match m in tokenFinder.Matches( text ) select m.Groups[1].Value ).Distinct();

// perform replace for each token...performance here will greatly vary based on the number of tokens to replace
foreach( string token in tokens )
{
    Regex replaceRegex = new Regex( token );
    text = replaceRegex.Replace( text, string.Concat( "!", token.Trim() ) );
}

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( "Complete in {0}ms.", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds );
```

Comment: You use Linq. I am using NET 2.0. :P However, when I tested this code with the same file, performance was (by an insignificant amount) slower.

Comment: @david - any chance that you can post more sample data? I'm curious about the discrepancy.